# Integrate new wxGrid in the old version 2.8.4

Tags: windows, visual-c++, wxwidgets, wxgrid

Currently I use the old version 2.8.4 of wxWidgets, now I need to use FreezeTo, the new wxGrid method presents in the new version 3.1.5.

How can I import the new wxGrid class in the old version 2.8.4?

I have tried looking for all the files that make up the new wxGrid class in wxWidgets 3.1.5. source file, and rename the new wxGrid class to wxGrid_3_1_5, in order to avoid conflicts.

Is there a more efficient way to integrate the new wxGrid class into the old wxWidgets?

Comment: @amedoro, it will be easier to just upgrade the whole library. wxAdv is no longer present and the good outweighs any negativity. Besides 2.8.4 is really old and the longer you postpone the harder the upgrade will be...

Comment: @Igor Upgrading from 2.8 to 3.1 is not necessarily easy at all, it can be several weeks of work for a larger codebase; it depends. Backporting one single function can be less work, if that's all one needs.

Comment: I looked at wx source code, what I would do is start by manually copying just the new `FreezeTo` function to 2.8.4 sources, along with all the lines that refer to variables with `freeze` in their name. It might be doable with a bit of manual work, maybe.

Comment: @LauriNurmi, it is a lot of work. And it will be more and more work every day it is not done. But it still might be easier than trying to get that function inside a control.

Comment: @famedoro, since you are working with 2.8.4, maybe it will be easier to just copy the whole wxGrid source. It self-preserved inside wxAdvanced library, so it might be easier than trying to port just one function.